# C - Need explanation on printf options' behavior

Tags: c, printf, primitive

Hi I have a double variable named outputSampleRate with value 0x41886a0000000000

I'm trying different combination of printf options and I get very confused by the output.

Here is the code:

```
    printf("\n\noutputSampleRate  0x%16x       \n", outputSampleRate);
    printf("outputSampleRate  0x%llx       \n", outputSampleRate);
    printf("outputSampleRate  0x%.llx       \n", outputSampleRate);
    printf("outputSampleRate  0x%.16x       \n", outputSampleRate);
    printf("outputSampleRate  0x%16llx       \n", outputSampleRate);
    printf("outputSampleRate  0x%.16llx       \n\n", outputSampleRate);
```

Here is the printout on console:

```
outputSampleRate %llx  0x               0
outputSampleRate %16x  0x41886a0000000000
outputSampleRate %.llx  0x41886a0000000000
outputSampleRate %.16x  0x0000000000000000
outputSampleRate %16llx  0x41886a0000000000
outputSampleRate %.16llx 0x41886a0000000000
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong:

```
%llx    print as long long (64 bit) in hex representation
%16x    print 16 digits, ignore leading 0s in hex representation
%.llx    ????what is this?
%.16x    print at least 16 digits in hex repesentation
%16llx   print 16 digits as a long long in hex representation
%.16llx  print at least 16 digits as a long long in hex representation
```

Besides, I have the following questions:

```
1. How does %llx give me 0x               0  ?
2. Why %.llx and %.16x behave differently   ?
```

Thank you for any input to save this C newbie.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Comment: From your question it is not clear what you want to achieve. If you just want to have a reproducible print out of a `double` in hexadecimal notation, use the `%a` format. This one is for floating point values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%llx` does not mean "print as `long long` in hex". It means **the argument is (has type) `long long`**. If you violate this requirement, your program has undefined behavior.

If you want to print the representation of a `double`, do something like:

```
double x;
uint64_t x_repr;
memcpy(&x_repr, &x, sizeof x_repr);
printf("%" PRIx64 "\n", x_repr);
```